# Get value from jsonelement's jsonarray with Java and Gson

Tags: java, arrays, json, arraylist, gson

I have this code:

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("My api url");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "MyUserAgent");

    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

    JsonElement element = new JsonParser().parse(reader);

    System.out.println(element);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My api response:

```
[
  {
    "id": 12345,
    "name": "1.0"
  }
]
```

I need to get the `name` parameter as a string, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: the name is a string no? `"1.0"`

Comment: @YCF_L yes, it is.

Comment: Ok, what did you mean by *I need to get the name parameter as a string, but I don't know how to do it*

Comment: I want to make a method that returns the name parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for :

```
JsonElement name = element.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("name");
```

**Output**

```
"1.0"
```

---

Or to get the value of name :

```
String name = element.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();
```

**Output**

```
1.0
```

Comment: If I need to compare the `name` value (version) to another, how I can do?

Comment: @alex3025 can you clarify your question more or by an example, I don't get you well

Comment: I want to exec code if the version that I get with `name` is greater than another string: "1.0.1"

Comment: @alex3025 this can be as another question, but I will give you a clue, you can add zeros to the end of the string which are low than your max version length, then remove the dots, and then convert the two strings to Integer and compare this two integers, for example in your case "1.0" -> "1.0.0" so you have "1.0.0" and "1.0.1" then -> "100" "101" then your action `if (Integer.valueOf("100") > Integer.valueOf("101"))`, as I said, If you don't understand my solution, you can post a question and I will try to answer you step by step

Comment: I'm going to post a question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230838/how-to-compare-2-version-strings-with-java

Comment: @alex3025 you question got many down-votes, because you don't post what have you tried, I would suggest to try a solution in your side, and then post your question :), I also suggest to remove your question

Comment: I'm going to try what you write in the comment